# Alerts, Dropdown Calendar of DateField, Cursors resulting in null value references once embedded

Tags: apache-flex, flash, adobe, flexbuilder, flash-builder

I have a Flex application embedded in a Flash application, which was working fine and currently works fine if not embedded. As of last Friday, when embedded the Alerts do not show (no error, just nothing), DateField Calendar dropdowns do not show (null value reference of  DateField), and dynamically showing the busy cursor errors (null value reference). My code for the Flex app did not change, and I can't think of any reason outside of Flash Player updates (which I think unlikely) or something has changed in the Flash application that is embedding it. Anyone ran into this or have any suggestions? Thanks is advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded?" Like, you're putting it in an html page? Or are you loading it into another flash/flex app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in Flex 3.2 SDK - Upgrade to 3.3